# Does any1 know why this is only reading every second line? after recognising "COM"

Tags: vb.net

```
While Not sr.EndOfStream
        line = sr.ReadLine
        If line.Contains("Year") Then
            currentYear = line.ToString
        ElseIf line.Contains("mandatory") Then
            moduleStats = "M"
        ElseIf line.Contains("optional") Then
            moduleStats = "O"
        ElseIf line.Contains("COM") Then
            modArray = sr.ReadLine.Split(",")
            ' Dim i As Integer = modArray.Length
            'ReDim Preserve modArray(modArray.Length + 2) 'ReDim statement to change the size of one or more dimensions of an array, 
            'Preserve you can resize that dimension and still preserve all the contents of the array

            ' modArray(i) = moduleStats
            ' modArray(i + 1) = currentYear.ToString()
            MsgBox(String.Join(",", modArray))

        End If
    End While
```

I have commented out a lot of the code within that particular else if but its returning every 2nd record and i have no idea why!! Any1 help me out Please?? note its does not matter how i split the document, this is the layout of the document..

Year 1

mandatory

COM137,Mathematics for Computing,2,20

COM140,Computer Technologies,1-2,20

COM147,Introduction to databases,1-2,20

COM163,Professional Practice, 1-2,20

COM180,Programming I,2,10

Year 2

mandatory

COM319,Networks and data communications,1-2,10

so it starts off by reading Computer Technologies line which is shouldn't it then jumps a the Introduction to databases line to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's because you're calling `ReadLine` twice.

Try changing:

`modArray = sr.ReadLine.Split(",")`

So that it reads:

`modArray = line.Split(",")`

Comment: yep that was it thanks very much been staring at this too long